# In apache maven, how to solve [ERROR] Error fetching link: .../package-list. Ignored it?

Tags: java, scala, maven, javadoc

I have a multimodule scala project that requires scaladocs to be attached to each of them. So I configured maven-javadoc-plugin to generate java/scala doc automatically:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <attach>true</attach>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-javadoc</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

However it turns out that this configuration doesn't automatically generate package-list, so I keep getting this error when a submodule is used by another:

> [ERROR] Error fetching link: .../package-list. Ignored it.

Is there a way to configure javadoc/scaladoc plugins to generate an empty package-list file if the package definition is not defined? Or there are better ways to avoid throwing this error?

Comment: This is not `scala`-specific, I’m also having this with plain `java` modules ☹

Comment: Thanks a lot! Added java tag

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the `maven-javadoc-plugin` to version `3.1.0` or higher gets rid of this error message.